# Static and customize Progress Bar Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiprogressbar

Since I'm new to learning Swift I might not be explaining this right in Swift... but here goes.

I have to use a progress bar for sport prediction apps. So I want a custom progress bar to remain in a constant value to explain the prediction for upcoming match. I have 2 questions:
**1.** can I make the value of the progress bar static and doesn't change though the second changes?
**2.** can I customise the movement direction? (on the picture, shows that the movement is from left to right. can I customise it so the movement will start from right to left?)

Here are the screenshot of the progress bar that I created: [progressBar]: http://postimg.org/image/jtv0d44ht/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "can I make the value of the progress bar static and doesn't change though the second changes?" 2. Yes you can customize the value but you need to apply some math trick to handle it. like if progress bar value is 40/100 then you need to do (100-40)/100.

Comment: I have to show the home team's prediction value. is it possible to show it in a progress bar? I tried it but the result is if I assign value 60, it starts to run from 60% to 100%. is it possible to make the value static and not changed at all? thank you..